# How to add new mime type to apache tika

Tags: java, apache-tika

This is my class for reading mime types. I am trying to add a new mime type(properties file) and read it.

This is my class file:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package check_mime;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import org.apache.tika.Tika;
import org.apache.tika.mime.MimeTypes;


public class TikaFileTypeDetector {

    private final Tika tika = new Tika();

    public TikaFileTypeDetector() {
        super();
    }

    public String probeContentType(Path path) throws IOException {

        // Check contents first
        String fileContentDetect = tika.detect(path.toFile());
        if (!fileContentDetect.equals(MimeTypes.OCTET_STREAM)) {
            return fileContentDetect;
        }

        // Try file name only if content search was not successful
        String fileNameDetect = tika.detect(path.toString());
        if (!fileNameDetect.equals(MimeTypes.OCTET_STREAM)) {
            return fileNameDetect;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Tika tika = new Tika();

        if (args.length != 1) {
            printUsage();
            return;
        }
        Path path = Paths.get(args[0]);

        TikaFileTypeDetector detector = new TikaFileTypeDetector();

        String contentType = detector.probeContentType(path);

        System.out.println("File is of type - " + contentType);
    }

    public static void printUsage() {
        System.out.print("Usage: java -classpath ... "
                + TikaFileTypeDetector.class.getName()
                + " ");
    }
}
```

From the [docs](https://tika.apache.org/1.8/parser_guide.html) I have created a custom xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <mime-info>
   <mime-type type="text/properties">
          <glob pattern="*.properties"/>
   </mime-type>
 </mime-info>
```

Now how do I add to my program and read it. Do I have to create a parser? I'm stuck here.

Answer (score 7):

This is covered in the [Apache Tika 5 minute parser instructions](http://tika.apache.org/1.8/parser_guide.html#Add_your_MIME-Type). To add support for Java .properties files, you should first create a file called `custom-mimetypes.xml` and populate it with something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mime-info>
  <mime-type type="text/properties">
     <_comment>Java Properties</_comment>
     <glob pattern="*.properties"/>
     <sub-class-of type="text/plain"/>
   </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

Next, you need to put that somewhere that Tika can find it, with the right name. It *must* be stored as `org/apache/tika/mime/custom-mimetypes.xml` on your classpath. The easiest thing to do is to create that directory structure, move the new file in, then add the root directory to your classpath. For deployment, you should wrap that up into a jar and put it on the classpath

You can use the Tika App to check your mime type file was loaded, if you're careful. With your code pacakged as a jar, run it as something like:

```
java -classpath tika-app-1.10-SNAPSHOT.jar:my-custom-mimetypes.jar org.apache.tika.cli.TikaCLI --list-supported-types | grep text/properties
```

Alternately, if you have it in a local directory, try something like

```
ls -l org/apache/tika/mime/custom-mimetypes.xml
# Check a file was found, with some content in it
java -classpath tika-app-1.10-SNAPSHOT.jar:. org.apache.tika.cli.TikaCLI --list-supported-types | grep text/properties
```

If that isn't showing your mime type, then you didn't get the path or filename correct, double check them

(Alternately, upgrade to a newer version of Apache Tika, as since r1686315 Tika has a Java Properties mimetype built in!)

Comment: "then add the root directory to your classpath"?? I am using netbeans IDE where I have created a package called `org.apache.tika.mime` which contains this file `custom-mimetypes` with contents as you have mentioned above

Comment: I don't know netbeans, sorry. The new custom mimetypes file *must* be present on the classpath with the exact path `org/apache/tika/mime/custom-mimetypes.xml` - any prefixes on it or missing bits of the path will mean that Tika won't recognise it

Comment: Yes the custom xml file is present in the class path. This is Directory structure in netbeans = `Check_Mime\build\classes\org\apache\tika\mime\custom-mimetypes.xml` and the class file is in same location

Comment: Check_Mime is the project name

Comment: Great tip on the org.apache.tika.cli.TikaCLI  check !

Answer (score 4):

In your `resources` folder add package `org\apache\tika\mime` and create file `custom-mimetypes.xml`.

Put the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mime-info>
  <mime-type type="custom-mime-type">
    <glob pattern="*.custom-extension"/>
  </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

Replace `custom-mime-type` with your mime type and `custom-extension` with your extension. 
Please check bellow the directory structure.

Btw you can also load [tike mime-types](https://github.com/apache/tika/blob/master/tika-core/src/main/resources/org/apache/tika/mime/tika-mimetypes.xml) locally by downloading that file and placing alongside `custom-mimetypes.xml` . This is helpful only when you need to change standard tike mime-types. One thing to remember you can not have same mime-type/extension in both xml.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Tika will detect your custom definition via Java resource loading and automatically add it to its own definitions: For that you need to name it custom-mimetypes.xml and put it into package org.apache.tika.mime within your codebase.

If you create a jar file from your classes, you also need to include your custom-mimetypes.xml in the jar.

Comment: Which package you are referring to? java package in my project?

Comment: So I just create a package named `org.apache.tika.mime` and add the custom xml file?

Comment: I get exception: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to parse the default media type registry`

Comment: Thats because your custom-mimetypes.xml contains an error: "properties file" is syntactically not a valid mimetype. Write something like:
<mime-type type="text/properties">.
But *.properties is already defined by Tika core, which returns mimetype text/plain for it.

Comment: I want it to detect as text/properties file not as text/plain type

Comment: I tried it with text/properties file but its still giving me the same error

Comment: I tired doing this. But the file's MimeType is still detected as application/x-bplist which is a file of extension .webarchive which you get when a file is downloaded. How do I avoid this?

Answer (score -3):

```
MediaType mediaType = detector.detect(stream, metadata);
        System.out.println("Detected Media Type: " + mediaType.toString());
        MimeType mimeType = config.getMimeRepository().forName(mediaType.toString());
        String extension = mimeType.getExtension();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. - [From Review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/13230440)

Comment: How does this add a new mime type? All it seems to be doing is fetching an existing one